# Does a PyUno Bridge object model exist?

Tags: python, pyuno

I've managed to access LibreOffice.calc, open my file, select my sheet and getValue() and getFormula()... That is, my job is (nearly) done, but... the PyUno bridge is just a bridge and not very Pythonic.

For instance, `for sheet in sheets:` throws the following exception: `TypeError: 'pyuno' object is not iterable`

So, the question is if somebody, somewhere, has an Open Source Pythonic library to the LibreOffice (calc) object model?

```
off = LibreOffice()
calc = off.Open(file)
sheets = calc.getSheets()
for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet.name)
    rng = sheet.Range("A1:C5")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should have done instead:

```
sheets = calc.getSheets()
sheet_names = sheets.getElementNames()

for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    print(sheet_name)
    sheet = sheets.getByName(sheet_name)
```

Code doesen't lie :D

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a thing, yet. I have been experimenting with such a thing myself here are work, not clear if it will ever be released. My approach was to take the doxygen output and use that as input to a code generator to create a set of wrapper classes, these could then be even implemented in python for test frames.